# Send file from frontend to NODEJS backend to convert XML to JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm sending xml files from frontend page to my backend NODEJS server using method post

FRONTEND simple code gating files and post to server
...

```
        `req = {
            method: "POST",
            url: 'api.com/sendfiles',
            data: {files: files},
        };`
```

...

BACKEND CODE

### req.body.files

```
`    {
      name: 'file.xml',
      size: 35003,
      url: 'blob:http://localhost/89bd5938-5cc4-48bc-809f-ab46c243ed7d',
      _file: {}
    }`
```

--
...

```
`req.body.files.forEach(async doc => {
  request.get(
    {
       url: doc.url,
     },
   function (error, response, body) {
      console.log (body, error, response);
   }
);`
```

...

need to work file blob files received in post request to get xml file and convert to json

Answer (score 0):

try this one,

```
const parser = require('fast-xml-parser');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const xmlToJSON = (xml) => {
  const jsonObj = parser.parse(xml, {
    ignoreAttributes: false,
    attributeNamePrefix: '_',
  });
  return jsonObj;
};

const processXMLFile = async (file) => {
  const response = await fetch(file.url);
  const xml = await response.text();
  const json = xmlToJSON(xml);
  return json;
};

const processFiles = async (files) => {
  const jsonFiles = [];
  for (const file of files) {
    const jsonFile = await processXMLFile(file);
    jsonFiles.push(jsonFile);
  }
  return jsonFiles;
};

const files = req.body.files;
const jsonFiles = await processFiles(files);
```

Comment: D:\code\bitapi\functions\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1327
>               throw new TypeError('Only absolute URLs are supported');

maybe because I'm working with localhost ?